# Models and Pivot Tables

Tags: phalcon

I have a custom written solution, which I'm porting over to Phalcon. This is my first run with Phalcon, and, though it's easy to use and well documented, I can't seem to find anything about linking models that are linked through a pivot table.

Here's the run down:

I have users. Users have stats. The two are linked with a table called users_stats. The table contains two columns: a user ID and a stat ID. I created a third class called Users_Stats to model after the pivot table.

User Model:

```
<?php
class Users extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasMany('stat_id', 'Users_Stats', 'user_id', array('foreignKey' => true));
    }
}
```

Stats Model:

```
<?php
class Stats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('stat_id', 'Users_Stats', 'id');
    }
}
```

Users_Stats Model:

```
<?php
class Users_Stats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasMany('user_id', 'Users', 'id');
        $this->hasMany('stat_id', 'Stats', 'id');
    }
}
```

I just want to be able to gather the stats based on users. I am not sure if all I'm missing is that each of the models needs to belong and hasMany (Stats has many User_Stats && User_Stats has many Stat; etc.). I know I'm missing something though.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ([source](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#relationships-between-models)):

User Model:

```
<?php
class Users extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasMany(
            'stat_id', 
            'Users_Stats', 
            'user_id', 
            array('foreignKey' => true)
        );
    }
}
```

Stats Model:

```
<?php
class Stats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasMany('stat_id', 'Users_Stats', 'id');
    }
}
```

Users_Stats Model:

```
<?php
class Users_Stats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('user_id', 'Users', 'id');
        $this->belongsTo('stat_id', 'Stats', 'id');
    }
}
```

User 1->many Users_Stats many<-1 Stats

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Sadly, it didn't work, BUT it did point me in the right direction. Turns out, all three of those Models needed to hasMany and belongsTo at the same time. I figured it out because I could get users from user_stats, but not vice-versa. I will post the answer below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)

Answer (score 3):

After some playing around, and some great help from Nikolaos Dimopoulos, here's something things I found out.

1. Classes can't have underscores.
2. A lookup table's model must belong to each of the classes, as well as must have many of those same classes.
3. Each class belonging to a lookup table's model must belong to the lookup table's model, as well as must have many of the lookup table's model.

User Model:

```
<?php
class Users extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('id', 'UserStats', 'user_id');

        $this->hasMany('user_id', 'UserStats', 'id');
    }
}
```

Stat Model:

```
<?php
class Stats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasMany('stat_id', 'UserStats', 'id');

        $this->belongsTo('stat_id', 'UserStats', 'id');
    }
}
```

UserStats Model:

```
<?php
class UserStats extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    /**
     * Set database name as there is no UserStats DB
     *
     * @return string
     */
        public function getSource() {
        return 'user_stats';
    }

    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('user_id', 'Users', 'id');
        $this->belongsTo('stat_id', 'Stats', 'id');

        $this->hasMany('id', 'Users', 'user_id');
        $this->hasMany('id', 'Stats', 'stat_id');
    }
}
```